# Adding <customHeaders> in webconfig causes 500 error in sub applications in IIS?

Tags: iis, http-headers, web-config, custom-headers

My web site is written by ASP.NET MVC 4 and hosted on IIS 6.2.
I need to add custom headers(X-Frame-Options,X-XSS-Protection etc.) to web config in main application.

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
        <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1"  />
        <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

After I did it, my sub apllications getting http 500 error.I have no idea why this happening.
I already tried  option.Also tried remove every customheaders from response headers in IIS, also tried add manually in response headers.

Can you give me an advice to fix this issue?

Comment: I already treid clear tag in httpprotocols tag in webconfig.

Comment: What the full contents of that 500 error page? Usually everything you need is inside.

Comment: Please post details about the 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the header at the Server level by using "HTTP Response Header" applet.

I think you are adding headers in the "Default Web Site" now. Default Site the header starting with "X-" will give error. I had faced this issue.

You can also try adding it in each App or virtual directory under "Default Web Site".